# Cakephp Recaptcha Not Working

Tags: php, cakephp, recaptcha

While i tried to add recaptcha plugin from http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/tbsmcd/2011/02/05/recaptcha_plugin_6 , following errors are shown.

> Strict (2048): Declaration of RecaptchaComponent::startup() should be
>   compatible with Component::startup(Controller $controller)
>   [APP/Plugin/recaptcha_plugin/Controller/Component/RecaptchaComponent.php,
>   line 17]
>
> Strict (2048): Declaration of ValidationBehavior::beforeValidate()
>   should be compatible with ModelBehavior::beforeValidate(Model $model)
>   [APP/Plugin/recaptcha_plugin/Model/Behavior/ValidationBehavior.php,
>   line 2]****

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be you are trying to use this CakePHP 1.3 plugin with CakePHP 2.x? The reason I ask is the name of the file `recaptcha_plugin` does not follow CakePHP convention. Follow the readme on the [Git Repo](https://github.com/tbsmcd/recaptcha_plugin).

It looks like you need to rename the plugin folder in the plugin directory:

```
/app/Plugin/Recaptcha
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr. Chuck. After i setup the plugin which you mention , it shows the error that

Strict (2048): Declaration of RecaptchaComponent::startup() should be compatible with Component::startup(Controller $controller) [APP/Plugin/Recaptcha/Controller/Component/RecaptchaComponent.php, line 17]

Error: The application is trying to load a file from the RecaptchaPlugin plugin

My plugin in App/Plugin/Recaptcha. And i followed the instructions only.

Comment: There are a few problems with the Recaptcha code. Search and replace any instance inside the plugin of `RecaptchaPlugin` with `Recaptcha`. Also, remove the `die()` statement in the `validation.beforeValidate`. One last thing, make sure you check the file permissions the `recaptchalib.php` in the Vendor directory.

Comment: Great. Got Capcha widget in my form. And How can i check it on controller function? Im using ajax form submission. i tried to use if($this->Recaptcha->validate()) { } . But not works.

Comment: One more issue Mr. Chuck. The plugin works in my local server only. The same error display in my host [BlueHost] which one work right in local. I changed all instances which you mentioned, it could not accepted by host.

Comment: Did you update your Recaptcha keys for the domain you are running on? http://www.google.com/recaptcha/whyrecaptcha

Comment: Can you please help me to complete this module. I have no idea about to check the captcha on controller functions?

Comment: You may have better luck reaching out to the creator of the module.